# gradle issue in android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

When i update gradle file in android it give me below issue. Trying lots of things like refresh, rebuild, sync with files, Invalidate caches but nothing work for me.

[image]

Comment: Check your grade, according to the image, you have used `compile` instead of `implenentation`, change all the `compile` to `implementation`. Also you have used `provided` instead of `compileOnly`. Please correct it!

Comment: When you say that you have tried "a lot of things" please provide information on what you have already tried.

Comment: you cannot use the `3.2.0` plugin with Android Studio `3.0.1`. update Android Studio to `3.2.1`... the Java compiler is pretty verbose about, what it does not likely about your project.